# How to fix error plotting "Package pgfplots Warning: Axis range for axis y is approximately empty; enlargi ng it (it is [0.0:0.0]) "

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I have a .csv file for example

```
x,y
0.0,0.0
0.01,0.00010774053043701307
0.02,0.00010774053043701307
0.03,0.00010774053043701307
0.04,0.00010774053043701307
0.05,0.00010774053043701307
0.06,0.00010774053043701307
0.07,0.00014664493119403256
0.08,0.0001915333704067139
0.09,0.00024240531068915437
0.1,0.0002992601430234413
0.11,0.0003620971867669429
0.12,0.00043091568966045687
0.13,0.0005057148278372159
0.14,0.0005864937058327506
0.15,0.0006732513565956097
0.16,0.0007659867414989382
0.17,0.000864698750352909
0.18,0.0009693862014180162
0.19,0.001080047841419221
0.2,0.0011966823455609558
0.21,0.0013192883175429826
0.22,0.0014478642895771137
0.23,0.0015824087224047762
0.24,0.0017229200053154453
0.25,0.0018693964561659246
0.26,0.0020218363214004856
0.27,0.0021802377760718568
0.28,0.002344598923863077
0.29,0.002514917797110189
0.3,0.002691192356825808
0.31,0.002873420492723518
0.32,0.003061600023243144
0.33,0.0032557286955768663
0.34,0.0034558041856961887
0.35000000000000003,0.003661824098379764
0.36,0.003873785967242066
0.37,0.004091687254762918
0.38,0.0043155253523178665
0.39,0.004545297580209419
0.4,0.004781001187699114
0.41000000000000003,0.005022633353040461
0.42,0.00527019118351271
0.43,0.005523671715455502
0.44,0.005783071914304324
0.45,0.006048388674626854
0.46,0.006319618820160134
0.47000000000000003,0.00659675910384859
0.48,0.006879806207882916
0.49,0.007168756743739781
0.5,0.007463607252222396
0.51,0.00776435420350194
0.52,0.008070993997159806
0.53,0.008383522962230694
0.54,0.008701937357246585
0.55,0.009026233370281507
0.56,0.009356407118997188
0.5700000000000001,0.009692454650689514
0.58,0.010034371942335868
0.59,0.010382154900643294
0.6,0.010735799362097478
0.61,0.011095301093012606
0.62,0.011460655789582054
0.63,0.011831859077929897
0.64,0.012208906514163285
0.65,0.012591793584425626
0.66,0.012980515704950653
0.67,0.013375068222117262
0.68,0.01377544641250525
0.6900000000000001,0.014181645482951866
0.7000000000000001,0.014593660570609158
0.71,0.015011486743002225
0.72,0.015435118998088259
0.73,0.01586455226431641
0.74,0.016299781400688516
0.75,0.016740801196820643
0.76,0.01718760637300547
0.77,0.0176401915802755
0.78,0.01809855140046705
0.79,0.018562680346285172
0.8,0.01903257286136933
0.81,0.019508223320359907
0.8200000000000001,0.01998962602896554
0.8300000000000001,0.020476775224031313
0.84,0.020969665073607736
0.85,0.02146828967702059
0.86,0.021972643064941514
0.87,0.022482719199459513
0.88,0.022998511974153237
0.89,0.023520015214164046
0.9,0.024047222676270005
0.91,0.024580128048960533
0.92,0.025118724952512047
0.93,0.025663006939064294
0.9400000000000001,0.026212967492697525
0.9500000000000001,0.026768600029510575
0.96,0.027329897897699563
0.97,0.02789685437763767
0.98,0.028469462681955465
0.99,0.029047715955622184
1.0,0.029631607276027882
1.01,0.029631607276027882
1.02,0.03022111353087026
1.03,0.03081619467761404
1.04,0.03141681742042154
.
.
.
4.900000000000003,0.7831223904577598
4.910000000000004,0.7971864038672304
4.9200000000000035,0.8116110293974611
4.930000000000003,0.8264066223751712
4.940000000000003,0.8415838659569086
4.950000000000004,0.8571537823360351
4.9600000000000035,0.8731277443569787
4.970000000000003,0.8895174875523898
4.980000000000003,0.9063351226194677
4.990000000000004,0.9235931483523778
5.0000000000000036,0.9413044650483672
5.010000000000003,0.9594823884058965
5.020000000000003,0.9781406639338477
5.030000000000003,0.9972934818916466
5.040000000000004,1.016955492780938
5.050000000000003,1.037141823410302
5.060000000000003,1.0578680935553668
5.070000000000004,1.0791504332375965
5.080000000000004,1.1010055006459807
5.090000000000003,1.1234505007268458
5.100000000000003,1.1465032044680505
5.110000000000003,1.1701819689049002
5.120000000000004,1.1945057578762506
5.1300000000000034,1.2194941635604382
5.140000000000003,1.24516742882191
5.150000000000004,1.271546470400699
5.160000000000004,1.2986529029782243
5.1700000000000035,1.3265090641542931
5.180000000000003,1.355138040371629
5.190000000000003,1.3845636938257693
5.200000000000004,1.4148106903997526
```

and I  try to plot  data from this file

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,report]{extarticle}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color} %red, green, blue, yellow, cyan, magenta, black, white
\setlength\parindent{5ex}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cool}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=1.5cm, top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,bindingoffset=0cm, footskip=-40pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{tabularray} 
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumiii}{\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}.\arabic{enumiii}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumiv}{\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}.\arabic{enumiii}.\arabic{enumiv}}
\setlength{\parindent}{1.25cm}
\linespread{1.15}
%\setlength{\parskip}{6pt}
\setcounter{page}{2}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{noitemsep}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\onehalfspacing

\newtheorem{definition}{Определение}[section]
\newtheorem{theorem}{Теорема}[section]

\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.17}


\begin{document}
begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{solution_a=5_n=1.csv}\datatable
\begin{axis}
[
xmin=0, xmax=5.12,
ymin=0, ymax=1.25,
    ytick distance = 5,
    grid = both,
    minor tick num = 1,
    major grid style = {lightgray},
    minor grid style = {lightgray!25},
    legend style={draw=none, fill=none},
    axis lines = left,
    xlabel = {$x$},
    ylabel = {$|\psi|^{2}_{n=3}(x)$},
    ylabel style={rotate=-90},
xtick={0, 1,2,3,4,5},
ytick={0, 0.2, 0.4;  0.6;  0.8;  1.0; 1.2},
x tick label style= {rotate=0,anchor=north}
]
\addplot [blue,thick] table [x=x, y=y] {\datatable};
\addlegendentry{$|\psi|^{2}_{n=3}(x)$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\vspace{-0.3 cm}
\caption{Probability $|\psi|^{2}_{n=3}(x)$ при $a = -5$}\label{fig:myplot}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

And I get the error:

```
Package pgfplots Warning: Axis range for axis y is approximately empty; enlargi
ng it (it is [0.0:0.0]) on input line 464.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   i
l.464 \end{axis}
```

I try to use xpf, but it's not work in tis case. How to plot this graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your code, I don't obtain the warning (it's a warning, not a error).

Your message warning contains *Package pgfplots Warning: (...) on input line 464.*, but we don't have 464 (or more) lines in your code (only 80 lines).

If I create your file named `solution_a=5_n=1.csv` (and suppress the 3 lines with only "." instead of two comma separated numbers, see the extract below)

```
1.03,0.03081619467761404
1.04,0.03141681742042154
.
.
.
4.900000000000003,0.7831223904577598
4.910000000000004,0.7971864038672304
```

or if I add:

```
\begin{filecontents}{solution_a=5_n=1.csv}
x,y
0.0,0.0
0.01,0.00010774053043701307
(continue)
5.190000000000003,1.3845636938257693
5.200000000000004,1.4148106903997526
\end{filecontents}
```

in the preamble (note that `\usepackage{filecontents}` is no longer needed in modern LaTeX installations)

and I fix some typos (in `\begin{figure}[h]` I have added the missing `\`, and I have replaced `ytick={0, 0.2, 0.4;  0.6;  0.8;  1.0; 1.2},` by `ytick={0, 0.2, 0.4,  0.6,  0.8,  1.0, 1.2},` as you need `,`instead of `;`),

the file compiles without error:

[image]

So, with the code you provided, and the corrections I said, the warning is gone (but the plotting is not what you expect as your are missing coordinates from x=1.04 to x=4.90, and so the gap is bound with a straight line).

There is also another warning with the code you provided: *LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s): [report].* It's the `report` in `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,report]{extarticle}`. I don't know this global option, which package uses it.

Take also a look at [pgfplots bar chart: single symbolic x coord results in "! Package pgfplots Warning: Axis range for axis x is approximately empty; enlarging it"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167224/pgfplots-bar-chart-single-symbolic-x-coord-results-in-package-pgfplots-warni?rq=1).